# outer div to inherit width of inner floated div

Tags: html, css

I m having two inner floated divs inside a single div

i want the outer to be in the center of the page so i have used margin:auto;

I want the outer div to inherit the width of the two child divs.

The example [here](http://cdpn.io/lCymk)

The html being -

```
<div class=area>

<div id=aleft>
    This is on the left
</div>
<div id=left>
    This is another on the left
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

For that in the outer div i used width inherit in the css but that did not work.

So for now i have used fixed with of 800px.

The css -

```
.area {
   margin: auto;
   background-color:black;
   color:orange;
   posiition:absolute;
   width:800px;
}
#aleft {
   float:left;
   width:200px;
   border:2px solid white;
}

#left {
   float:left;
   width:500px;
   border:2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "inherit the width of the two child divs" ?

Comment: @Era They mean if 2 `div`s inside the container are `300px` and `400px` (width) the container should auto size to `700px` because thats whats inside it. (I think)

Comment: +1 @Ruddy
the div class area should automatically the have the total width of the two child divs ie. 200+500=700

Answer (score 3):

By default `<div>` are block elements, it'll take the entire available width. Change it to an`inline-block` element by applying `display:inline-block` for the outer div and remove it's `width` set in pixels.

[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HAlgt)

Comment: Correct, could also use `display: table;` to keep it centered how you have it. +1 from me.

Comment: But that is removing the margin:auto as i want the div to be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya Read my comment :) [**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ksant)

Comment: `display:inline-block` won't work... however `display:table` will

Comment: anything can be done without tables? i think tables are a bit outdated ;)

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya simply apply `text-align:center` for the parent element of the div, in this case `body` check the updated pen

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya This isnt a table. Its `display: table`, its fine to use. + tables are still ok to use but we mainly use them to display data... not design.

Comment: don't forget to remove `posiition:absolute;`.. first of all it's spelled wrong, and second it's not needed at all

Comment: @Tilwin Joy yeah never mind.. I was using CSS that he had in his original question which didn't work with `display:inline-block`... it was missing `text-align:center` for the `body` - that's why

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<table>`.

```
<table style="position: relative; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 300px;">
            left
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 400px;">
            right
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```